# Convert a union of literals to and array of literals in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to extract the second type out of the first one, so I don't have to maintain both?

```
type possibleValue = "A" | "B"
type allValues = ["A", "B"]
```

I'm also open to go the other way around and have actual objects or classes and extract the type information using `typeof`, `keyof` and such.

---

My specific problem is that I have a message queue that contains differently typed messages. They can be differentiated with one property I call `kind` (called [tagged or discriminated unions in the advanced types section in the typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)). Now I have a function that gets one of those messages from the queue, and a function that processes one of those messages. The first function takes an array with all `kind`s and the latter a union of all message types. I don't want those two function getting our of sync where the first one could possibly get a message the second one cannot process.

The code is probably easier to understand:

```
interface Square {
    kind: "square";
    size: number;
}
interface Rectangle {
    kind: "rectangle";
    width: number;
    height: number;
}
interface Circle {
    kind: "circle";
    radius: number;
}

// adding a type to Shape but not KindsOfShapes would lead to a runtime
// exception I want to avoid.
type Shape = Square | Rectangle | Circle;
type KindsOfShapes = [Square["kind"], Rectangle["kind"], Circle["kind"]]

function getShape (kinds: KindsOfShapes) {
  return messageQueue.get(kinds)
}

function area(s: Shape) {
    switch (s.kind) {
        case "square": return s.size * s.size;
        case "rectangle": return s.height * s.width;
        case "circle": return Math.PI * s.radius ** 2;
    }
}

const shape = getShape(["square", "rectangle", "circle"])
const area = area(shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to extract the second type out of the first one, so I don't have to maintain both?
>
> ```
> type possibleValue = "A" | "B"
> type allValues = ["A", "B"]
> ```

No.

You can [follow the discussion here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3628). For maybe a weird solution with decorators, read [the last comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3628#issuecomment-296885693).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible you can do this.

```
// add an element to the end of a tuple
type Push<L extends any[], T> =
  ((r: any, ...x: L) => void) extends ((...x: infer L2) => void) ?
  { [K in keyof L2]-?: K extends keyof L ? L[K] : T } : never

// convert a union to an intersection: X | Y | Z ==> X & Y & Z
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

// convert a union to an overloaded function X | Y ==> ((x: X)=>void) & ((y:Y)=>void)     
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never>;

// convert a union to a tuple X | Y => [X, Y]
// a union of too many elements will become an array instead
type UnionToTuple<U> = UTT0<U> extends infer T ? T extends any[] ?
  Exclude<U, T[number]> extends never ? T : U[] : never : never

// each type function below pulls the last element off the union and 
// pushes it onto the list it builds
type UTT0<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT1<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT1<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT2<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT2<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT3<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT3<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT4<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT4<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT5<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT5<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT6<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT6<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT7<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT7<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT8<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT8<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT9<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT9<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTTX<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTTX<U> = []; // bail out
```

`type Test = UnionToTuple<"a | "b">  // ["a", "b"]`